# Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for JMeter

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

[image]

I got an error

> Cannot create JDBC driver of class 'org.postgresql.Driver' for connect URL 'jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.169:5432/synapse?autoReconnect=true'

Answer (score 5):

You most probably forgot to add the Postgres Driver class in lib folder.

Read this:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html

Answer (score 4):

Give it a try using

```html
jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.169:5432/synapse?tcpKeepAlive=true
```

If this does not work check the Postgres Driver class in lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

- Add appropriate version of Postgres Driver jar to the lib folder

[image]

- Remember to Restart Apache Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, it turned out that the reason was in the "space" when inserting before the connection address

```
_jdbc:postgresql://
```

After deleting it, the error disappeared